# Very high network usage in background mode for android/chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app that is pretty heavy on data (it's a home camera monitoring app). Due to the nature of the backend system it interacts with, it opens many `img src` HTTP connections  to the server. The server basically streams images via JPEG from the camera (inefficient, I know) over the img src (HTTP) connection continuously.

The odd thing that I'm seeing is that if the app goes into the background, chrome continues to keep the img src connections open. This results in *huge* network bandwidth in the background.

I've tried detecting when I am switching to the background - and replacing the img src tag with a local image. my logic was that it will terminate the TCP connection.

But it doesn't help.

I'm stumped for the following reasons:

1. Why is the connection kept open even if I change the image to a local file
2. How on earth do I stop my app from receiving data in the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured out the problem. To force stop Chrome to terminate all connections, calling `window.stop()` works for me.

So each time I detect a switch to background, I am calling window.stop() which effectively terminates all open connections and therefore kills the image stream.

Credit: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73395